# "String" in Mysql Colum Cannot Be Read

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have this column

```
id |  subject  | message
1  |  register | Hello, welcome to $siteurl
```

I already get the colum by using php file and call the echo there

```
echo $email['subject'];
echo $email['message'];
```

The result will be like this

> register Hello, welcome to $siteurl

before that I already put this code

```
<?php
$siteurl = 'domain.com';
```

after  code in top

but the result still give me $siteurl instead of domain.com

can someone help me? how to show the string that I save in database into php page

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace that string first. E.g.,

`$message = str_replace('$siteurl', $siteurl, $email['message']);`

`echo $message;`

Comment: how if i got many string in there? for example $siteurl $username $email

Comment: You can use the same function `str_replace()` to replace whatever value you want.

Comment: and how about the next line can be detect? because my email message only show in one long line. without <br/>

Comment: You can use `str_replace()` multiple times. Just replace after another.